# Uncaught ReferenceError: displayText is not defined at HTMLAreaElement.<anonymous>

Tags: events, onclick, onclicklistener, event-listener

Any time I try to add a function to an onclick or event listener I get the titled error. I don't understand why it does this. Here is the code:

```
export class Clickables {
    constructor(game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.doOnce = false;
        this.textDisplaying = false;


        this.ladder = document.getElementById("ladder");
        this.steering = document.getElementById("steering");
        this.propellor = document.getElementById("propellor");
        this.outAtSea = document.getElementById("outAtSea");
        this.atTheShip = document.getElementById("atTheShip");


        this.ladderMSG = document.getElementById("ladderMSG");
        this.steeringMSG = document.getElementById("steeringMSG");
        this.propellorMSG = document.getElementById("propellorMSG");
        this.outAtSeaMSG = document.getElementById("outAtSeaMSG");
        this.atTheShipMSG = document.getElementById("atTheShipMSG");


        this.eventRect = document.getElementById("eventRect");


        //an array holding all the clickables
        this.clickables = [this.ladder, this.steering, this.propellor,
            this.outAtSea, this.atTheShip];
        //an array holding all the messages
        this.messages = [this.ladderMSG, this.steeringMSG, this.propellorMSG,
            this.outAtSeaMSG, this.atTheShipMSG];
    }


    //NOTE:
    //may want tp read text one char at a time for aesthetics
    //may want to fade out text for aesthetics


    displayText(message) {
        //prevent the messages from being clicked again
        this.eventRect.style.display = "none";
        //display the given message
        message.style.display = "flex";


        if (this.textDisplaying) {
            this.textDisplaying = false; //do only once


            //setTimeout does a thing after set amount of time
            setTimeout(() => {
                //allow the text boxes to be clicked again
                this.eventRect.style.display = "initial";
                //remove the given message
                message.style.display = "none";
            }, 5000);
        } //if(this.textDisplaying)
    } //displayText()


    update(startButtonPressed) {


        if (startButtonPressed && !this.doOnce) {
            this.doOnce = true;


            for (let i = 0; i < this.clickables.length; i++) {
                let self = this.clickables[i];


                self.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();


                    //do awesome stuff here
                    if (this.id === 'ladder') {
                        //stuff to do if LADDER is clicked
                        displayText(messages[0]);


                    } else if (this.id === 'steering') {
                        //stuff to do if STEERING is clicked
                        displayText(messages[1]);


                    } else if (this.id === 'propellor') {
                        //stuff to do if PROPELLOR is clicked
                        displayText(messages[2]);


                    } else if (this.id === 'outAtSea') {
                        //stuff to do if OUTATSEA is clicked
                        displayText(messages[3]);


                    } else if (this.id === 'atTheShip') {
                        //stuff to do if ATTHESHIP is clicked
                        displayText(messages[4]);
                    }
                }, false);
            } //for()
        } //if(startButtonPressed)
    } //update()


    draw(context) {}


} //class Clickables
```

I didn't try much this time because I don't know what to do; last time I spent hours trying to find a workaround; it just seems like event listeners don't like functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I guess the event listener `onclick` had a limited scope so I put the `displayText` function inside of `update()` and changed some of the this. variables into constants also put inside the `update()`. Here is the final code and it works:

```
export class Clickables {
    constructor(game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.doOnce = false;

        this.ladder = document.getElementById("ladder");
        this.steering = document.getElementById("steering");
        this.propellor = document.getElementById("propellor");
        this.outAtSea = document.getElementById("outAtSea");
        this.atTheShip = document.getElementById("atTheShip");

        //an array holding all the clickables
        this.clickables = [this.ladder, this.steering, this.propellor,
            this.outAtSea, this.atTheShip];
    }

    update(startButtonPressed) {

        let textDisplaying = false;
        const eventRect = document.getElementById("eventRect");
        const ladderMSG = document.getElementById("ladderMSG");
        const steeringMSG = document.getElementById("steeringMSG");
        const propellorMSG = document.getElementById("propellorMSG");
        const outAtSeaMSG = document.getElementById("outAtSeaMSG");
        const atTheShipMSG = document.getElementById("atTheShipMSG");
        const messages = [ladderMSG, steeringMSG, propellorMSG, outAtSeaMSG, atTheShipMSG];

        //NOTE:
        //may want tp read text one char at a time for aesthetics
        //may want to fade out text for aesthetics
        function displayText(message) {
            //prevent the messages from being clicked again
            eventRect.style.display = "none";
            //display the given message
            message.style.display = "flex";

            if (!textDisplaying) {
                textDisplaying = true; //do only once

                //setTimeout does a thing after set amount of time
                setTimeout(() => {
                    //allow the text boxes to be clicked again
                    eventRect.style.display = "initial";
                    //remove the given message
                    message.style.display = "none";
                    textDisplaying = false;
                }, 5000);
            } //if(this.textDisplaying)
        } //displayText()


        if (startButtonPressed && !this.doOnce) {
            this.doOnce = true;

            for (let i = 0; i < this.clickables.length; i++) {
                let self = this.clickables[i];

                self.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    //do awesome stuff here
                    if (this.id === 'ladder') {
                        //stuff to do if LADDER is clicked
                        console.log('LADDER CLICKED');
                        displayText(messages[0]);

                    } else if (this.id === 'steering') {

                        console.log('STEERING CLICKED');
                        //console.log(this.steeringMSG);
                        //stuff to do if STEERING is clicked
                        displayText(messages[1]);

                    } else if (this.id === 'propellor') {

                        console.log('PROP CLICKED');
                        //stuff to do if PROPELLOR is clicked
                        displayText(messages[2]);

                    } else if (this.id === 'outAtSea') {

                        console.log('OUTATSEA CLICKED');
                        //stuff to do if OUTATSEA is clicked
                        displayText(messages[3]);

                    } else if (this.id === 'atTheShip') {

                        console.log('ATTHYSHIP CLICKED');
                        //stuff to do if ATTHESHIP is clicked
                        displayText(messages[4]);
                    }
                }, false);
            } //for()
        } //if(startButtonPressed)
    } //update()

    draw(context) {}

} //class Clickables
```